# autoref for subsection

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ref, autoref

When I use autoref for subsection, I want the in-text to be `section 1.1` instead of `subsection 1.1`. How to do that. I tried to write it with `ref` as:

```
section \ref{sec:subsection}
```

But the problem is that I want my references to be clickable (using `hyperref`) and with ref the word `section` becomes un-clickable (only the number portion) while with `autoref` the whole word `section 1.1` becomes clickable. Can you help?

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{First}\label{sec:section}
\subsection{Sub}\label{sec:subsection}
\autoref{sec:section} and \autoref{sec:subsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put like this below:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\subsectionautorefname{section}
\begin{document}
\title{Title Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\section{First}\label{sec:section}
\subsection{Sub}\label{sec:subsection}
\autoref{sec:section} and \autoref{sec:subsection}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me if I load the `babel` package with the `ngerman` option. There aren't errors but `\def\subsectionautorefname` simply hasn't any effect. I messed around and I'm sure `babel` is the problem. Do you have any ideas how to make this work with `babel`?

Comment: I made it work by using `\addto\extrasngerman{\def\subsectionautorefname{section}}`